# MySQL COUNT Filtering

Tags: mysql, join, count

This is my first post on stackoverflow, although I've used it as a reference for a long time. So thanks for all the guidance you've provided me in the past. I really appreciate it. Here is my issue:

I have two tables, one called `USERS` and one called `SIGNIN`

```
USERS  
-----------------
userid | password

SIGNIN
--------------
suserid | date
```

I would like to count the number of times that a user has signed in over the period of the last week.

Here's what I've got:

```sql
SELECT userid, password FROM USERS JOIN (SELECT suserid, COUNT(*) AS logins 
FROM signin 
WHERE WEEKOFYEAR(date) = WEEKOFYEAR(CURDATE()) && signin.suserid = users.userid) 
GROUP BY userid
```

I just can't wrap my head around how to `JOIN` a subquery and make it count each individuals' logins (date column) and return an individualized number for each individual. I know that query is totally jacked up but I'm just at that point, you know, where I've become so confused that I just need some guidance.

Any help and direction would be fantastic! I've read so many pages to no avail. Thanks, in advance!

** and thank you for the edits. They'll help in the future when I post again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't try to do a subquery, just do the join and group by user id.  Also, you want YEARWEEK so you are matching both the year and week, not just the week from any year.

```
select userid, count(*)
    from users inner join signin on userid=suserid and yearweek(`date`) = yearweek(curdate())
    group by userid;
```

left join instead of inner join if you want results of 0 for users who haven't signed in.
This follows what I assume is your intent of "last week" meaning the week of the current date (by default starting Sunday, but see the optional mode parameter to yearweek).

Note that the users table here is completely optional; you could just do:

```
select suserid, count(*) from signin
    where yearweek(`date`) = yearweek(curdate())
    group by suserid;
```

but I'm guessing you may be getting other columns from user or wanting to exclude signins for deleted users.

Comment: I don't see why using a subquery would be an issue, but the point about changing to YEARWEEK is very good.

Comment: the questioner was confused and trying to do a subquery to do what a join naturally does.  subqueries can be powerful in some cases, but mysql can handle them rather differently than a seemingly equivalent join; they should be avoided unless you know you need one.

Comment: Ah, yes, that seems a fair point. Do you think you could incorporate some of this reasoning into your answer? I'm not insisting, it's just that a mere *‘Don't try to do a subquery’* without any explanation may sound ambivalent to some. ‘Don't try to do a subquery because it won't do the job properly’? We shouldn't forget that many people can come across this thread and may try applying answers here to their problems.

Comment: Exactly what I needed. So I was way overcomplicating it by trying to do a subquery. You were also exactly right about the "last week" meaning the week of the current date (which defaults to starting on Sunday). REALLY appreciate the help, stackoverflowers! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

sThis should be it:

```
select suserid, count(suserid)
    from signin
    where date > NOW() - INTERVAL 1 WEEK
    group by suserid;
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a subquery if I understand you correctly.

Something like:

```
SELECT a.userid, a.password, count(b.date) AS logins
FROM users a
INNER JOIN signin b ON a.userid = b.suserid  and WEEKOFYEAR(date) = WEEKOFYEAR(CURDATE())
GROUP BY a.userid, a.password
```

Sorry - haven't got time to try the query to double check syntax, but hopefully will set you in right direction

Edit:  If you want to include users with 0 logins, change to LEFT OUTER JOIN

Answer (score 0):

you don't need a join here. what you need is

```
SELECT userid, password, (SELECT COUNT(*) 
FROM SIGNIN
WHERE WEEKOFYEAR(date) = WEEKOFYEAR(CURDATE()) AND signin.suserid = users.userid) AS logins
FROM USERS WHERE 1 GROUP BY userid;
```